# Integral against a test function is bounded implies function is locally integrable

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, distribution-theory

Let $f $ be a <s>continuous</s> function such that

$$ \left| \int_{0}^{1} \phi(x) f(x)~dx \right| \le C_{\phi}$$

for every $\phi \in \mathcal{D}(0,1)$. Is it true that

$$ \left| \int_{K} f(x)~dx \right| \le C $$ for every compact $K \subset [0,1]$? In other words can we conclude that $f \in L^{1}_{loc}(0,1)$?

I think it could be true by the arbitrary-ness of the test function but I am having trouble constructing an argument.

Comment: Actually your first condition implies $f=0$. This is because if the inequality is true for all test functions $\phi$, then by replacing it with a scaled version $a\phi$ and dividing by $a$, you can conclude the inequality holds with $C=0$. Now the usual fundamental lemma of calculus of variations tells you $f=0$.

Comment: Anyway regardless of what I said above, the very fact that $f$ is continuous means this is all very trivial and obvious. The integral of $f$ is bounded, using monotonicity of integrals, by $\sup|f|\cdot(1-0)=\sup|f|$ (which is finite by the extreme value theorem).

Comment: @peek-a-boo Thanks for your reply, I realise now that my question was not phrased as I intended. I have edited it now. The first constant $C$ depends on the test function one considers and $f$ is a function whose regularity a-priori we don't have any information on. I wish to know if $f$ is integrable on a compact set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a proof. The assumption is: for all $\phi \in C_c^\infty(0,1)$ with $\phi\ge0$ the integral $\int_0^1 f(x) \phi(x)dx$ exists in the Lebesgue sense and is finite.

First, assume $f\ge0$. Let $K\subset(0,1)$ be compact. Take non-negative $\phi\in C_c^\infty(0,1)$ such that $\phi=1$ on $K$ (this can be achieved by mollification). Then
$$
\int_K f(x) dx \le \int_0^1 f(x) \phi(x) dx < + \infty,
$$
and $f$ is locally integrable.

Second, consider the general case. By definition of the Lebesgue integral and by assumption, we have that the integrals of the positive and negative part of $f\cdot\phi$ exist and are finite. Then $\int_0^1 (f(x))^+ \phi(x) dx < \infty$ for all smooth and non-negative $\phi$ implies local integrability of $f^+$ by the first part of the proof. Similarly, $f^-$ is locally integrable, which implies local integrability of $f$.

Comment: Got it thank you! I think what I was missing was that the definition of the Lebesgue integral actually implies that the integrals of $f_{\pm}$ are finite.